# What is it that's being passed to transform function of Series?

Tags: pandas, transform, series

I'm using `transform` function of `Series`, but something got me confused.

I have searched the documentation of Pandas and googled,but couldn't find the answer.

When I use `np.sum`, the result is:

```
s = Series(range(7))
s.transform(lambda x:x + np.sum(x))

0     2
1     4
2     6
3     8
4    10
5    12
6    14
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

So, I think `x` is the element of the `Series`.But when I use `x.sum`,the result is:

```
s.transform(lambda x:x + x.sum())

0    29
1    30
2    31
3    32
4    33
5    34
6    35
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

`x` looks like a Series. And when `s` is a dataframe, it will get the same result.
I am confused. Who can help me answer my question, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I read the source code. I find that the `transform` function depend on `aggregate` function.And It will try a regular apply first:

```
def aggregate(self, func, axis=0, *args, **kwargs):
    # Validate the axis parameter
    self._get_axis_number(axis)
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
    if result is None:

        # we can be called from an inner function which
        # passes this meta-data
        kwargs.pop('_axis', None)
        kwargs.pop('_level', None)

        # try a regular apply, this evaluates lambdas
        # row-by-row; however if the lambda is expected a Series
        # expression, e.g.: lambda x: x-x.quantile(0.25)
        # this will fail, so we can try a vectorized evaluation

        # we cannot FIRST try the vectorized evaluation, because
        # then .agg and .apply would have different semantics if the
        # operation is actually defined on the Series, e.g. str
        try:
            result = self.apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
        except (ValueError, AttributeError, TypeError):
            result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return result
```

so, first it will pass a scalar to the user-defined-function. The `transform` function will invoke `s.apply(lambda x: x + x.sum())`, it will raise a `AttributeError`, then it will pass the whole series to the user-defined-function. For example:

```
def func(x):
    print(type(x))
    print(x)
    return x + x.sum()

s.transform(func)

<class 'int'>
1
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
Name: A, dtype: int64

0    29
1    30
2    31
3    32
4    33
5    34
6    35
Name: A, dtype: int64
```